i couldnt redirecting my django app from int to string in the url
I'm having trouble with my Django URL patterns. The URL exercise4/1/ is not matching any of my defined patterns, even though I have a pattern defined for exercise4/int:month/. Can you help me figure out why it's not matching?"
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound,HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect

month_chalenge = {
    'JAN': 'IT IS NEW YEAR CONGRATS',
    'FEB' : 'WELCOME TO NEW MONTH OF FEBURARY',
    'APRIL': 'FASTING MONTH',
    'MAY': 'EDEPENDENCE DAY'
}

def month_chalenge_bynumber(request, month):
    months = list(month_chalenge.keys())
    redirect_month = months[month-1]

    return HttpResponseRedirect("/exercise4/" + redirect_month)

def monthchalenge(request, month):  
    try:
        chalenge_list = month_chalenge[month]
        return HttpResponse(chalenge_list)
    except:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('sorry ! we dont have data for this data')

